# Pre-2014 mecha anime with a unicorn/Pegasus mech combining with the main mech

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

From what I recall of the show, it involves aliens or something invading the Earth, from space I assume, as I remember them having space battles with the mech in latter episodes.

The main character was a teenaged student who ended up piloting the mech because it landed near him during the invasion. I feel like I remember the mech either had two compatible pilots or there were two mechs; both mech pilots were male in high-to-middle school.

Later on in the series, they have a unicorn/Pegasus mech combine with the main mech for a power up and I feel there were other mechs that they find which are able to combine with their main mech.

I'm sure this show isn't *Aquarion*, *Neon Genesis Evangelion* or the *Gundam* series.

Comment: https://brave.fandom.com/wiki/Pegasus_Saber?

Comment: [Aldnoah.Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldnoah.Zero) might match parts of it.